# My C++ program is not keeping track of my 3n+1 longest sequence

Tags: c++

The final output for this code if you enter 1 then 5 is...

> The longest sequence with a start value in the range [1, 5] has 8 elements.

But instead I'm getting {16 elements}.

I believe the issue might be with my counter system, and returns. Does anyone have any advice on how I can fix this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
// Functions
void getUserInput(int &start, int &end);
int longestSequence(int minimum, int maximum);
int getNextElement(int x);
string generateSequence(); // still need to write definition
int counter = 1;

int main()
{
    int minimum;
    int maximum;
    int last;

    getUserInput(minimum, maximum); // 
    last = longestSequence(minimum, maximum); // starts longest sequence counter 

    cout << "The longest sequence with a start value in the range [" << minimum
         << ", " << maximum << "] has " << last << " elements." << endl;

    return 0;
}

void getUserInput(int &start, int &end)
{
    cout << "Enter the min of the range for the sequence to start " << endl;
    cin >> start;
    cout << "Enter the max of the range for the sequence to start " << endl;
    cin >> end;
}

int getNextElement(int x) // // This function does the 3n+1 computation
{

    if (x != 1) // Checks for the end of the sequence. The end being when the number is 1.
    {
        counter++;
        if (x % 2 == 0) // checks if its even
            getNextElement(x / 2); // takes the new number through the function again
        else
            getNextElement(x * 3 + 1); // takes the new number into the function again
    }
    cout << "This is in getNextElement" << counter << endl;
    return counter; // this is returned as length in the longestSequence function.
}

int longestSequence(int minimum, int maximum) // this function compares all the sequence lengths within the range of minimum and maximum.
{
    int max = 0; // Longest seqence

    for (int i = minimum; i <= maximum; i++)
    {
        int length = getNextElement(i); // length is a temp that will hold the longest seqence

        if (length > max) // this loop validates if the newest "length" from the sequence is bigger than the previous one

            cout << "This is in the longest sequence loop ... length" << length
                 << endl;
        cout << "This is in the longest sequence loop AS MAX" << length << endl;
        max = length; // after the first run of the loop, max stores the longest seqence, and updates it after each run of the for loop if its longer
        // counter = 1; not sure why this is here
    }
    cout << "This is in longest sequence.... max " << max << endl;
    return max;
}
```

Comment: Over commenting can make your code harder, not easier, to read. And stuff like this: `// Functions` is kind-of insulting.

Comment: `max = length; // after the first run of the loop, max stores the longest seqence, and updates it after each run of the for loop if its longer` No actually, it doesn't. Start your investigation here.

Comment: `// counter = 1; not sure why this is here` think about it a bit longer and you might. Seriously, you were closer when you asked essentially this question last week.

Answer (score 3):

Reset your counter to 1 before calling `int length = getNextElement(i)`.
You are getting 16 as output because each call to `getNextElement(i)` resumes the `counter` from where the last function call left.

```
counter=1;
int length = getNextElement(i);
```

just as you missed it right in your own code

```
// counter = 1; not sure why this is here
```

also, max is not updated to the greater length, but any length because it is outside the scope of the `if` for checking the greater one. So, put curly braces for the `if` condition and move the `max=length` inside it.

Comment: @user4581301 ah yes, didn't notice the braces were missing. Thanks

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you I'm going to try it out